# Wordpress displaying custom metabox with categories

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So here is my code:

```
function pages_inner_custom_box2( $post ) {

    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'pages_noncename' );

    // The actual fields for data entry
    $cats = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pages_categories_field', true);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( (get_categories() ) as $category):
        if( $category->cat_ID != 14 ):
            foreach( $cats as $values ) {
                if( $values ==  $category->cat_ID ){
                    $checked = "checked=checked";
                } else {
                    $checked = false;
                }
            }
            echo'<li id="cat-'.$category->cat_ID.'">
            <input type="checkbox" name="pages_categories_field[]" id="'
            .$category->cat_ID.'" value="'
            .$category->cat_ID.'" '
            .$checked.'> <label for="'
            .$category->cat_ID.'">'
            .__($category->cat_name, 'pages_textdomain' )
            .'</label></li>';
        endif;
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

So what this does it displays the categories in a metabox, now the problem is after I update the selection, and I select more then one category, it will only `MARK AS CHECKED` just one category.The data is saved right in the database.The problem is only on the selection.

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I deleted my answer, Bainternet's more complete. :::: Reproducing as comment: *If you properly formated and indented your code, the problem would be clear at a first glance. You are doing the `echo` outside the `foreach`. A good IDE is quite helpful when programming: [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org/).*

Answer (score 2):

you code is ok but you have some minor errors so:

```
function pages_inner_custom_box2( $post ) {

    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'pages_noncename' );

    // The actual fields for data entry
    $cats = get_post_meta($post->ID,'pages_categories_field',true);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach((get_categories()) as $category):
        $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
        if($cat_id != 14):
            $checked = (in_array($cat_id,(array)$cats)? ' checked="checked"': "");
            echo'<li id="cat-'.$cat_id.'"><input type="checkbox" name="pages_categories_field[]" id="'.$cat_id.'" value="'.$cat_id.'"'.$checked.'> <label for="'.$cat_id.'">'.__($category->cat_name, 'pages_textdomain' ).'</label></li>';
        endif;
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

and make sure you save it as an array in your save_post callback function 
something like this:

```
update_post_meta($post_id,'pages_categories_field',$_POST['pages_categories_field']);
```